# VBA - Autofilter then copy the result into the new sheet

Tags: vba

I am trying to do the macro which can do autofilter and copy the visible row , then paste them into the new sheet by using VBA. my code as below:

```
 Option Explicit

Sub lab()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet
    Dim mycoll As Collection
    Set mycoll = New Collection
    Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim c As Range
    Dim lastrow As Long
    lastrow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = sh1.Range("B4:F" & lastrow)
    With rng
        .AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=sh1.Range("I1"), Criteria2:=sh1.Range("I2"), Operator:=xlOr
        .AutoFilter field:=3, Criteria1:=sh1.Range("K1"), Criteria2:=sh1.Range("K2"), Operator:=xlOr
        .AutoFilter field:=4, Criteria1:=sh1.Range("M1"), Criteria2:=sh1.Range("M2"), Operator:=xlOr
    End With
    Set ws = Worksheets.Add
    ws.Name = sh1.Range("I1").Value & "-" & sh1.Range("I2").Value
    rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy ws.Range("A1")
    rng.AutoFilter
    sh1.Activate

End Sub
```

my problem is the code only work correctly for the first new sheet. then it always create the sheet with the same content. I tried to find the root issue , could you please help assist on this ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. When there is a problem with your code, you never use `On Error Resume Next`! It only does not let VBA 'telling' you what problem the code has...
2. If your code names the newly created sheet using:

```
ws.Name = sh1.Range("I1").Value & "-" & sh1.Range("I2").Value
```

second time, if the concatenation of the two cells value is the same, VBA cannot name a sheet with the same name like an existing one. The raised error should have a clear description but your code jumps over it, because of `On error Resume Next`.

3. If you really need/want to use a similar sheet name, try placing a suffix. For doing that, you can use the next function:

```
Function shName(strName As String) As String
   Dim ws As Worksheet, arrSh, arrN, maxN As Long, k As Long, El
   
   ReDim arrSh(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.count - 1)
   For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        If ws.Name = strName Then
            shName = strName & "_" & 1
            Exit Function
        End If
         If InStr(ws.Name, strName & "_") > 0 Then arrSh(k) = ws.Name: k = k + 1
   Next
   If k = 0 Then shName = strName: Exit Function 'if no such a name exists
   ReDim Preserve arrSh(k - 1)
   'determine the bigger suffix:
   For Each El In arrSh
        arrN = Split(El, "_")
        If CLng(arrN(UBound(arrN))) > maxN Then maxN = CLng(arrN(UBound(arrN)))
    Next
    shName = strName & "_" & maxN + 1
End Function
```

It should be called from your existing code replacing the line

```
ws.Name = sh1.Range("I1").Value & "-" & sh1.Range("I2").Value
```

with

```
ws.Name = shName(sh1.Range("I1").Value & "-" & sh1.Range("I2").Value)
```

Comment: @thangvc91 Have a nice weekend, too!

Comment: Sorry Bro, you declared E1 , but didn't assign type of data for it, May you help explain what is this ? . I tried with the function above, however no luck :(

Comment: @thangvc91 Why don't you simple copy the function like it is? It is not `E1`, it is `El` (EL) and declaring in that way it has been declared as `Variant`. What does "no luck" means? This is not a comment able to help me what problem you have...

Comment: Sorry Bro , my bad , so now just try again , your code work correctly. Appriciated for for help Bro :)